# Can an object in a cache be removed during a function call within that object?

Tags: c#, caching, thread-safety

Given the code:

```
private static readonly object GetMyObjLock = new object();
public static MyObject GetFromCache()
{
    var key = "MyObj";
    var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
    if (cache[key] == null)
    {
        lock (GetMyObjLock)
        {
            if (cache[key] == null)
            {
                cache.Add(key,
                    new MyObject(), null,
                    Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }   
    }
    return (MyObject) cache[key];
}
```

And the call:

```
var myObj = GetFromCache();
myObj.PerformMethod();
```

With some code listening on another thread that does:

```
if(message == "invalidate")
{
    Httpcontext.Current.Cache.Remove("MyObj");
}
```

Two questions:

- Will `PerformMethod` always complete?
- Is there any opportunity for `myObj` to equal `null` between the `GetFromCache()` method and `PerformMethod` call?

Comment: What do you mean by "Will PerformMethod always complete"?  You didn't even show us the code for that method.  How could we know?

Comment: @rory.ap I mean is it guaranteed to complete if say during the call the listener removes it from the cache during the method.  Will it throw exceptions (eg "this object no longer exists") or will it finish then remove it?

Comment: Removing an object from the cache does not "destroy" it.  It merely becomes eligible for garbage collection.  That won't happen, the *myObj* reference makes sure.  You do appear to forget to lock in the other thread, hopefully you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix it is use the output of the `Add` function to see if the item you added was actually added to the cache, if it already exists it will return the previous instance, if it did not exist it returns `null`. When it returns null you just set the object you passed in as the 2nd parameter as your result to return from the function.

```
private static readonly object GetMyObjLock = new object();
public static MyObject GetFromCache()
{
    var key = "MyObj";
    var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
    MyObject result;

    //Try to pull from the cache.
    result = (MyObject)cache[key];
    if(result == null)
    {
        //This lock is used to make sure the MyObject constructor is not called 
        // concurrently, it is not for thread safe access to the cache.
        lock(GetMyObjLock)
        {
            //Check to see if anyone made a new object while we where waiting.
            result = (MyObject)cache[key];
            if(result == null)
            {
                var newObject = new MyObject();

                //Try to add to cache, if the object was already added by someone who 
                // does not use the GetMyObjLock this function returns the previously 
                // added instance.
                result = (MyObject)cache.Add(key,
                    newObject, null,
                    Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

                //If result is null then we successfully added a new 
                // item, assign it to result.
                if(result == null)
                    result = newObject;
                }
            }
        }
    }        
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Understand that cache is thread safe, but assuming the `MyObject` constructor is expensive (say it pulls data from a database) we'd only want to call it once.  In this context does locking make sense?

Comment: @TomGullen In that case yes, it does make sense. Also, see my updated answer I changed it a bit, you don't acutally need to loop. I am going to update the answer again to use the lock.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this timing of the threads:

Thread 1:

```
var myObj = GetFromCache();
public static MyObject GetFromCache()
{
    var key = "MyObj";
    var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
    if (cache[key] == null)
    {
        lock (GetMyObjLock)
        {
            if (cache[key] == null)
            {
                cache.Add(key,
                    new MyObject(), null,
                    Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Thread 2:

```
if(message == "invalidate")
{
    Httpcontext.Current.Cache.Remove("MyObj");
}
```

Thread 1:

```
    return (MyObject) cache[key];
}
myObj.PerformMethod();
```

and it will break your implementation

A possible fix would be to store the `new MyObject()` in a local variable, then add it to the cache and then return the local variable. This will work, because it's a strong reference:

```
var myobject = new MyObject();
cache.Add(key,
myobject, null,
Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
return myobject;
```

Comment: You should check the result of `cache.Add`, if it returns a non null value the `myobject` you passed in was not added to the cache. The `Add` function acts more like a `GetOrAdd` except it returns `null` on a successful  add.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: if every user considers the `lock (GetMyObjLock)`, that should not be necessary